# @try - catch block in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, try-catch-finally, nsexception

Why doesn't @try block work?
It crashed the app, but it was supposed to be caught by the @try block.

```
 NSString* test = [NSString stringWithString:@"ss"];

 @try {
    [test characterAtIndex:6];

 }
 @catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
 }
 @finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not something else because the exact code you have pasted above works fine. 2010-07-29 16:45:57.677 test[93103:207] Exception: *** -[NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds 2010-07-29 16:45:57.678 test[93103:207] finally

Comment: You can replace NSString* test = [NSString stringWithString:@"ss"]; with NSString* test = @"ss";

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Now I've found the problem.

Removing the `obj_exception_throw` from my breakpoints solved this. Now it's caught by the `@try` block and also, `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` will handle this if a `@try` block is missing.

Comment: IF you hit continue when the debugger breaks, you should see the exception gets thrown and caught by your handler.

Answer (score 150):

All work perfectly :)

```
 NSString *test = @"test";
 unichar a;
 int index = 5;
    
 @try {
    a = [test characterAtIndex:index];
 }
 @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
    NSLog(@"Char at index %d cannot be found", index);
    NSLog(@"Max index is: %lu", [test length] - 1);
 }
 @finally {
    NSLog(@"Finally condition");
 }
```

Log:

> [__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
>
> Char at index 5 cannot be found
>
> Max index is: 3
>
> Finally condition

Comment: Correct but a bit misleading - remember that the @finally block gets executed in BOTH cases, i.e. regardless of whether exception was or was not thrown.

Comment: Yeah, I miss this :)

Comment: Please fix as @Elendurwen noted.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is not Java. In Objective-C exceptions are what they are called. Exceptions! Don’t use them for error handling. It’s not their proposal.
Just check the length of the string before using characterAtIndex and everything is fine....

Comment: Using try-catch in Objective-C is generally not recommended because it can potentially mess up the ARC.