# Objective-c Try/Catch not catching

Tags: objective-c, ios, try-catch-finally, nsexception

Is there a reason why the following wouldn't work?

```
@try {
    CFGetTypeID( NULL );
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
```

Similar to the [try/catch question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363612/try-catch-block-in-objective-c-problem), only it seems the above block crashes everytime. I know my debugger is setup correctly, as I setup a try/catch above from the other question:

```
// Test working try catch
NSString* test = [NSString stringWithString:@"ss"];

@try {
    [test characterAtIndex:6];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}

// Now test NULL entry
@try {
    CFGetTypeID( NULL );
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a very simple reason. Namely, `CFGetTypeID(NULL)` isn't throwing an exception. It's crashing. You can't catch crashes like this.