# Try-Catch Error Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, try-catch-finally

I am trying to get Captions from a given instagram picture, however if there is no caption the app throws an exception and crashes. How would I implement `@try` and `@catch` to do this. Here is what i have so far:

```
@try {
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",entry[@"user"][@"full_name"]] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text[@"caption"][@"text"]]];
    [modal show];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
}
@finally {
  //Display Alternative
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [exception reason] instead of just exception in your NSLog statement.

Comment: I really dont know how to could you tell me how?

Comment: I assume you are also throwing the exception?  The use of exceptions for common situations like this is discouraged in Objective-C.  Exceptions are for...well...exceptional situations that the program cannot recover from.  Instead why not use an `NSError` object and signal the user if there is no caption.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"Exception %@", [exception reason]);`

Comment: @borrrden could you please show me an example of this i am kind of a novice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654653/how-to-use-nserror-in-my-iphone-app Like this

Comment: I tried doing it right now however it did not print anything nor did it stop the app from crashing @asafreedman

Comment: P.S. Is it throwing an exception or simply crashing (see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745581/objective-c-try-catch-not-catching?rq=1 )

Comment: @borrrden could you show me how to implement the NSerror way with my code above im having trouble following the first link that you sent me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a good use of exceptions and `try`-`catch`-`finally` blocks. You say that you get the exception if the caption is `nil`. So, what precisely do you want your app to do in order to gracefully handle this situation? Not show the dialog at all? Then you might do something like:

```
NSString *user = entry[@"user"][@"full_name"];
NSString *caption = text[@"caption"][@"text"];

if (caption != nil && caption != [NSNull null] && user != nil && user != [NSNull null]) {
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:user message:caption];
    [modal show];
}
```

Or perhaps you want to show something else if those are `nil`:

```
NSString *user = entry[@"user"][@"full_name"];
NSString *caption = text[@"caption"][@"text"];

if (caption == nil || caption == [NSNull null])
    caption = @"";     // or you might have @"(no caption)" ... whatever you want
if (user == nil || user == [NSNull null])
    user = @"";

RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:user message:caption];
[modal show];
```

Or, if you have the source code for `RNBlurModalView`, perhaps you can diagnose why precisely it's generating an exception when the caption is `nil`, and fix that issue there.

There are lots of possible approaches, dependent upon precisely what you want the app to do in these situation, but exception handling is undoubtedly *not* the right approach. As the [Dealing With Errors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) section of the *Programming with Objective-C* guide, exceptions are intended for unanticipated "programmer errors", not simple logic errors, and as they say:

> You should not use a try-catch block in place of standard programming checks for Objective-C methods.

Comment: It didnt work here is what comes `libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: `2013-08-06 23:52:32.878 Floadt[2589:c07] -[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3102678
2013-08-06 23:52:32.880 Floadt[2589:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3102678'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: @prnk28 Your error is telling you that the object is `[NSNull null]`. So just add checks for that, too. See revised answer. I'm assuming the error is coming from caption being `[NSNull null]`, so this edit should do it. If not, you have to identify precisely which object is getting set to `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: It still gives me the same error.

Comment: @prnk28 Looking at the error more closely, it's `objectForKeyedSubscript` (which is called when you use the `[]` syntax). So, either `entry` is `[NSNull null]` or `text` is `[NSNull null]` or `entry[@"user"]` is `[NSNull null]` or `text[@"caption"]` is `[NSNull null]`. You have to examine these values and figure out which one is giving you the `[NSNull null]` value.