# canOpenURL a special string crash

Tags: ios, crash

I have faced a tough problem.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"numberplate://"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    NSLog(@"it can");
}
```

Just create a empty project, insert the codes above into the method of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `appdelegate.m`

I run it on simulator, it runs ok.
I run it on my Device,iOS 7.0.4, it crash.

But i run it on other people's device, it runs ok.

So, the problem is just occur on my device.

Also, if I change the string `@"numberplate://"` to any other strings, it also runs ok.

Has anybody faced this problem?

==========add edit=============

@demosten

```
@try {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"numberplate://"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally"); 
}
```

I change the code like this. But it can not catch the exception.

Comment: what's the crash log?

Comment: There is no stack information. Just has a line indicator "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x442a6a0)"

Comment: Have you tried using a `@try @catch` block? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363612/try-catch-block-in-objective-c shows how to use and a hint how to avoid debug breaks before `@catch` handles the problem

Comment: It is not with the string (I checked on my iPod running on iOS 7)

Comment: does it also crash if you uninstall the "numberplate" app ?

Comment: @JeanLuc   i do not install an app with the schema "numberplate"

Comment: so why do you need this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any custom code in your appDelegate in the method below?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{}
```

Inappropriate handler could possible be a reason.

Comment: No, if i change a character the code just like below,it runs ok.       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"numberplate11://"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    NSLog(@"it can");
}

Comment: just add "11" or any other characters, it also runs ok.